# Convert SQL table to mongoDB document

Tags: c#, sql, mongodb

What's the best way to convert a SQL database, let's say 1 table, to a mongoDB document?

I guess I could use a C# driver and implement a loop, which selects each row in the table and saves that in Mongo.. However, I am looking for a better way to convert a lot of data..

Comment: MongoDB's philosophy is to push as much of this sort of thing to the driver / app level ... so I'd agree with Matt below ... your best bet is using the C# not only because it will save you *LOT* of hassle (with it's nice BSON lib) but also because you can deal with many of the data conversion issues much easier than say a dump or export, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The driver way is by FAR the most straight forward. The import/export tools are fantastic, but *only* if you are using them as a pair. You are in for a wild ride if your table includes dates and you try to export from the db and import into mongo.

You are lucky too, being in c#. We are using ruby, and have a 32million row table we migrated to mongo. Our ending solution was to craft an insane sql statement in postgres that output json (including some pretty kludgy things to get dates going properly) and piped the output of that query on the command line into mongoimport. It took an incredibly frustrating day to write, and is not the sort of thing that can ever really be changed.

So if you can get away with it, use ado.net with the mongo driver. If not, I wish you well :-)

(note that this is coming from a total mongo fanboi)

Comment: besides date format, are there any other types Mongo doesn't like during conversion?

Comment: date was the real killer for us, because mongo sees it as a 64bit number of ticks since the epoch, and everything else we use uses 32bit dates. We had issues importing in tsv mode, because aparently according to 10gen, a quoted string can't have a line break in a tsv file. We ran into other issues too, but they were more specific to our tools.

Answer (score 13):

This is the import script that I am using for Importing data  from SQL server to Mongodb located on my box. 
This code will just create a similar table(existing in SQL DB) in MongoDB.
You can supply the table list to import as comma seperated and all of them would be imported without problems.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> tablelist = new List<string>();
    if (!args[0].Contains(','))
        tablelist.Add(args[0]);
    else
        tablelist.AddRange(args[0].Split(','));
    string sqlconnectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost/?safe=true;w=1;wtimeout=30s";
    var safemode = SafeMode.True;
    MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(connectionString);
    MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase("testdb");
    MongoCollection<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument> coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test");
    //coll.Find().Count();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string table in tablelist)
    {

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlconnectionstring))
        {
            string query = "select * from " + table;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                /// Delete the MongoDb Collection first to proceed with data insertion

                if (db.CollectionExists(table))
                {
                    MongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(table);
                    collection.Drop();
                }
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                List<BsonDocument> bsonlist = new List<BsonDocument>(1000);
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (i == 1000)
                    {
                        using (server.RequestStart(db))
                        {
                            //MongoCollection<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument> 
                            coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(table);
                            coll.InsertBatch(bsonlist);
                            bsonlist.RemoveRange(0, bsonlist.Count);
                        }
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    ++i;
                    BsonDocument bson = new BsonDocument();
                    for (int j = 0; j < reader.FieldCount; j++)
                    {
                        if (reader[j].GetType() == typeof(String))
                            bson.Add(new BsonElement(reader.GetName(j), reader[j].ToString()));
                        else if ((reader[j].GetType() == typeof(Int32)))
                        {
                            bson.Add(new BsonElement(reader.GetName(j), BsonValue.Create(reader.GetInt32(j))));
                        }
                        else if (reader[j].GetType() == typeof(Int16))
                        {
                            bson.Add(new BsonElement(reader.GetName(j), BsonValue.Create(reader.GetInt16(j))));
                        }
                        else if (reader[j].GetType() == typeof(Int64))
                        {
                            bson.Add(new BsonElement(reader.GetName(j), BsonValue.Create(reader.GetInt64(j))));
                        }
                        else if (reader[j].GetType() == typeof(float))
                        {
                            bson.Add(new BsonElement(reader.GetName(j), BsonValue.Create(reader.GetFloat(j))));
                        }
                        else if (reader[j].GetType() == typeof(Double))
                        {
                            bson.Add(new BsonElement(reader.GetName(j), BsonValue.Create(reader.GetDouble(j))));
                        }
                        else if (reader[j].GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                        {
                            bson.Add(new BsonElement(reader.GetName(j), BsonValue.Create(reader.GetDateTime(j))));
                        }
                        else if (reader[j].GetType() == typeof(Guid))
                            bson.Add(new BsonElement(reader.GetName(j), BsonValue.Create(reader.GetGuid(j))));
                        else if (reader[j].GetType() == typeof(Boolean))
                        {
                            bson.Add(new BsonElement(reader.GetName(j), BsonValue.Create(reader.GetBoolean(j))));
                        }
                        else if (reader[j].GetType() == typeof(DBNull))
                        {
                            bson.Add(new BsonElement(reader.GetName(j), BsonNull.Value));
                        }
                        else if (reader[j].GetType() == typeof(Byte))
                        {
                            bson.Add(new BsonElement(reader.GetName(j), BsonValue.Create(reader.GetByte(j))));
                        }
                        else if (reader[j].GetType() == typeof(Byte[]))
                        {
                            bson.Add(new BsonElement(reader.GetName(j), BsonValue.Create(reader[j] as Byte[])));
                        }
                        else
                            throw new Exception();
                    }
                    bsonlist.Add(bson);
                }
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    using (server.RequestStart(db))
                    {
                        //MongoCollection<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument> 
                        coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(table);
                        coll.InsertBatch(bsonlist);
                        bsonlist.RemoveRange(0, bsonlist.Count);
                    }
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What reference have I to add to use the type MongoServer, MongoDatabase and so on? I have MongoDB.BSON, MongoDB.Driver and MongoDB.Driver.Core, but those line code are red in VIsual Studio.

Comment: I'm also looking to run this code but can't compile with current MongoDB driver package. Classes MongoServer, MongoDatabase are not found ? Thanks, LA Guy

Answer (score 1):

I had to create tool for doing that.
It uses bcp.exe to export data to xml, then convert it to json using Newtonsoft JSON.NET and then mongoimport to import it.  It took less then a day, but dates are not supported.

Some code below (very uncleaned:)

bcp.exe uses syntax like:
bcp.exe "SELECT  * from GeoData.dbo.Airports FOR XML RAW('Row'),ROOT('Root'),ELEMENTS" queryout D:\TEMP\tmp1045.tmp -Uxxxx -Pxxxx -Sxxxx -w -r "" -q

json:

```
var r=XmlReader.Create("file://D:/1.xml");
    XmlDocument xdoc=new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(r);
    string result="";





    //o["Root"]["Airport"];
    foreach(XmlNode n in xdoc.ChildNodes[0]){
        var rr= JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(n);    

        JObject o=JObject.Parse(rr);    

        var co=o.Children().Children().First();     

        foreach (JToken c in co.Children().Where(cc=>cc.Type==JTokenType.Property).ToList()){                   
            var prop=c as JProperty;            
            double d;
            if (double.TryParse(co[prop.Name].Value<string>(),out d))
            {
                co[prop.Name] = d;
            }           
            //c.Value<string>().Dump();
            //c.Value<string>().Dump();
            //co[c.Name]
        }

        //co["APT_Latitude"].Value<decimal>().Dump();       
        result=result + co.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None)+"\r\n";


    }
    File.WriteAllText("D:/1.json",result);

    //result.Dump();
```

Mongoimport:
D:\MongoDB\mongoimport.exe -c "test" -d "MongoStatic" 1.json >1

Answer (score 1):

If you're up with playing with Ruby, I've make a gem that helps you do this: http://mongify.com/.

Source code can be found: https://github.com/anlek/mongify/

Really easy and straight forward defining of your schema and how it should translate into mongodb. Including embedding, renaming tables, renaming fields and a bunch of other options.

Answer (score 0):

Both the Norm & samus c# mongo drivers support strongly typed classes to be passed as documents. Means its cool as Nhiberbate and LINQ to SQL.

SO my idea is, you can use a LINQ to SQL to create a entity in c# (classes representing tables) to retrieve the data from sql server and you can use the same strongly typed class for insertion in mongo db.

Make sure that your classes should have a **mongo identifier** attribute (in NoRM) in any one of the field. This is to generate a unique id for a document.