# How to convert whole sql Script to mogodb using asp.net?

Tags: sql, asp.net, mongodb

I refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348185/7939571 code but it will convert only tables not script.

I want to convert sql script to mongodb using asp.net

Answer (score 0):

in that above refer link answer itself.

There is 4 Steps.

1. Upload Script.
2. Create Connection.
3. Execute Scripts from this and get all tables list.
4. For loop for table list for mongo db convert code in above link.