# MongoDB newbie - Storing Sql Server Table Data as Json Data in a Collection

Tags: json, mongodb

Does this use of MongoDB make sense ?

I'm very new to MongoDB ( 2 days ) and I need advice on this design.

I want to export / convert Sql Server tables data ( < 1000 Rows each ) to
MongoDB collections. I want to convert the sql data to JSON string data and then
save that as a single string "column/object" where the collectionname = sqlservertablename.

Given this design, I would retrieve all the JSON Data at once using the collectionname and then return the 
 json string to my Asp.Net MVC form which can render the data.
On the client, changes can be made and then I would save all the json data back to MongoDb.
This design is almost like using MongoDb as a text/flatfile for each "Table".

Does this make sense ?
Any links on doing this type of thing ?

Thanks, LA Guy

EDIT: shows how to convert sql server table to BSON document.
[Convert SQL table to mongoDB document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372630/convert-sql-table-to-mongodb-document?rq=1)
I will review this and see if it makes sense to do this.

Comment: I'd say no, but that's extremely subjective - IMO the entire question as it stands is in the "primarily opinion based" close reason danger zone. What would be the expected benefit of doing this?

Comment: Hi, I have many individual tables with different data in them. I'm looking for a generic way to store the data as a "json document"  that I would insert, update like I would do a "flat file".  I guess there is NO benefit beyond using a MongoDB data store vs Cloud File Storage.

Comment: There may be a facet that I fail to see, but when reading your question it sounds like you're going to store say 1000 records as a big block, and shove those back and forth to the client(s) for CRUD operations. That sounds like a **massively** inefficient approach with tons of wasted bandwidth. But if that's the route you want/need to go I suspect a cloud object or file storage would be at least as appropriate as using mongo,

Comment: @fvu  " a massively inefficient approach with tons of wasted bandwidth" yes, this sounds very bad ... I need to reconsider this. I'm reviewing a SO Post on converting sql table to a BSON document.  I trying to understand if I can use MongoDB vs Sql server more efficiently for "small tables" Thanks ! :)

Comment: Let me clarify that statement: if you send over a set of 1000 records to just edit 1 or a few, and then send back the entire block - which is how I read ` I would retrieve all the JSON Data at once using the collectionname and then return the json string to my Asp.Net MVC form which can render the data. On the client, changes can be made and then I would save all the json data back to MongoDb` suggests that most of the data that gets thrown back and forth will not change, and thus be overhead/wasted bandwidth?

Comment: @fvu Yes, that is correct but it is mostly a read / display app once the data is created. There can be changes and I can "batch" the edits into one "save" event to reduce bandwidth. Thanks :) I guess I'm treating the data as a "document" and not individual rows.